# How can I change owner back to root?

Tags: permissions, sudo, chown, ownership

So, I did a stupid thing...

I was installing some software (Java SE 7, if you must know) from a tarball, and I got tired of using `sudo`, so I went and changed the owner of my `/usr` directory to myself.

```
$ sudo chown -R sammy /usr
```

**Whoops!**

Since `sudo` lives in `/usr/bin/`, it also changed owner.  Now, I can't use it anymore.  Have I accidentally been caught in a sudo-Catch 22?  I can't use `apt-get install` or any number of other essential features of my shell environment.

```
$ sudo
sudo: must be setuid root
```

**Is there a way to change the owner of this directory (and subdirectories, too) back to `root`?**

Comment: What is the exact command that you ran?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I tried right away.  However, any invocation of `sudo` throws the error quoted above.

Comment: I will edit the question to include the exact command, @searchfgold6789.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restart the machine, boot into recovery (you should end up being root without having to type in any password). Proceed to `chown -R`. I think it should work. Report back on how it goes.

Comment: I've never booted into recovery.  Presumably, I have to make a choice in `grub`, where I have a menu of possible kernels to boot with?

Comment: Yes, you will have lines with `<kernel number>` and `<kernel number> (recovery)`, select one of the recovery ones.

Comment: I changed the entire `/usr` directory tree back to `root` ownership, but `sudo` is still **(!)** throwing the same error.

Comment: @SammyBlack Next step is `chmod +s /usr/bin/sudo`, which will set the setuid bit

Comment: Thank you @Wolfer, @Yet\ Another\ User for the help.  Everything seems to be back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

Man, you really did it, all `/usr` have almost essentials binaries, but lets repair your `sudo` first:

As root in the recovery console, you should remount the filesystem as read/write first:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

Then reboot and *try* to login, if you get more "Must be suid" errors repeat the process using sudo from the tty:

```
sudo chmod u+s /path/to/the/binary/you/screwed
```

Be careful next time and try to use `-R` `--recursive` with baby gloves.